# Flutter/Dart upload pre-signed multipart zip to s3 adds extra header, which causes zipfile to be unzippable

Tags: flutter, dart, amazon-s3, http-headers, multipart

I'm trying to upload a zipfile to AWS S3 with a presigned url.
I get the pre-signed url which seems to work great with Postman. With Flutter it also works, to some extend.

The problem however is that when uploading via Flutter (I used [this snippet](https://gist.github.com/orestesgaolin/69c112893532e1dd0e8fe01cb07ffc86)), it will upload the zipfile, but adds an extra 184 bytes to the header containing following:

```
--dart-http-boundary-z86XWhmTq935Bbfwfv.7UA+FIOU5nE4eqfUsZTh6PnGj+HBeAYH
content-type: application/octet-stream
content-disposition: form-data; name="out.zip"; filename="out.zip"
```

This header causes most built-in unzip tools to be unable to unzip the file.

I was able to unzip it using osx's built-in `unzip` command, but when downloading via Safari for example I get the 'Decompression Failed` message in the downloads section.

On Windows I failed to unzip altogether, even with [7-Zip](https://www.7-zip.org).

Is there a way to remove the header so it uploads just the zip file as-is without adding extra headers?

Disclaimer: I'm not a Flutter/Dart dev by core.

Thanks!

**EDIT 1:**
To create the signed URL (following AWS docs), I use following lambda function:

```js
'use strict'

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({ region: process.env.AWS_REGION });
const s3 = new AWS.S3();

const URL_EXPIRATION_SECONDS = 300;

exports.handler = async function(event, context, callback) {
  const body = event.body || {};
  return await getUploadURL(JSON.parse(event.body).projectNumber)
}

const getUploadURL = async function(projectNumber) {
  let Key = `${projectNumber}.zip`;
  
  if (!projectNumber) {
    const randomID = parseInt(Math.random() * 10000000)
    Key = `${randomID}.zip`;
  }
  
  // Get signed URL from S3
  const s3Params = {
    Bucket: process.env.UploadBucket,
    Key,
    Expires: URL_EXPIRATION_SECONDS,
    ContentType: 'application/zip',
    // This ACL makes the uploaded object publicly readable. You must also uncomment
    // the extra permission for the Lambda function in the SAM template.
    // ACL: 'public-read'
  }

  console.log('Params: ', s3Params)
  const uploadURL = await s3.getSignedUrlPromise('putObject', s3Params)

  return JSON.stringify({
    uploadURL: uploadURL,
    Key
  })
}
```

Comment: Can you check the uploaded file, and confirm if it has some extra bytes at the end too? It seems like the server isn't recognizing the mime format.

Comment: Hi, I didn't notice before but indeed there is some --dart-http-boundary added add the end too...

In that example I used application/octet stream, but it also gives the same with application/zip

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm suspicious of these lines in your snippet (remove them):

```
  request.headers.addAll({
    'Content-Type': mime,
  });
```

I don't think it's helpful to set the content type of the overall request - after all, that should remain as "multipart". If you want to give a content type to one of the parts, you do that where you add the file (i.e. on line 49 of your snippet). See the documentation of `MultipartRequest`.

```
var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', uri)
  ..files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(
      'package', 'build/package.tar.gz',
      contentType: MediaType('application', 'x-tar'))); // content type added here
```

Comment: Hi, problem is that I need to use a presigned s3 url from AWS to upload objects, and it need to be a PUT request, which on its turn need a content-type set. I'm directly uploading to s3 without using a backend, I just use a lambda function to create that signed url. (added the code to the original question)

Comment: Add the content type in the `fromPath`, rather than on the headers. Show your whole dart code, and temporarily remove the progress stuff to simplify it.